# Symbol exporting problem using __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, dllexport

I use __declspec(dllexport) with several methods in a library. But one of the symbols do not get exported properly. The value in question is called "restart". I've given the output from dumpbin.exe, below:

```
1    0 0002DB27 ev_err = @ILT+2850(_ev_err)
          2    1 0002DADC m_foutput = @ILT+2775(_m_foutput)
          3    2 0002D361 m_free = @ILT+860(_m_free)
          4    3 0002D505 m_free_vars = @ILT+1280(_m_free_vars)
          5    4 0002D055 m_get = @ILT+80(_m_get)
          6    5 0002D95B m_ident = @ILT+2390(_m_ident)
          7    6 0002D80C m_inverse = @ILT+2055(_m_inverse)
          8    7 0002D0F5 m_mlt = @ILT+240(_m_mlt)
          9    8 0002D339 m_ones = @ILT+820(_m_ones)
         10    9 0002D43D m_rand = @ILT+1080(_m_rand)
         11    A 0002DC3F m_resize = @ILT+3130(_m_resize)
         12    B 0002D465 m_zero = @ILT+1120(_m_zero)
         13    C 0002D3A7 px_foutput = @ILT+930(_px_foutput)
         14    D 0002DA2D px_free = @ILT+2600(_px_free)
         15    E 00092DE0 restart = _restart
         16    F 0002DB45 set_err_flag = @ILT+2880(_set_err_flag)
         17   10 0002D550 v_foutput = @ILT+1355(_v_foutput)
         18   11 0002D839 v_free = @ILT+2100(_v_free)
```

This seems to indicate that restart did not get exported properly but I can't figure out why.

I use the following line to export the variable:

```
extern  __declspec(dllexport) jmp_buf   restart;
```

What is the reason for this anomaly and how can I resolve it?

Comment: why are you using extern keyword? Is this method's code out of your library ?

Comment: No. It's the source of a library called meschach. The extern is used in the header and I used dllexport with it because tagging the definition gives an error (the one in my comments to jamm's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your "restart" identifier is data, not code.  It probably should have been named "restart_state".  Exporting data from a DLL is a supported scenario but a good way to blow your foot off.  The client code has to have strict binary compatibility with the DLL code.  That's a very questionable proposition for setjmp(), the saved state is highly implementation dependent.

You are much better off exporting functions that make the setjmp() and longjmp() calls and keep the jmp_buf private.

Comment: Actually I do not make direct use of this symbol. I only tried to export it because one of the binaries (another dll) which links to this, gave an undefined symbol error at compile time. I think it's being used indirectly via another method. There's a definition for "catch"(!!) which raises this error if used in my source. I can't figure out the exact mechanics but I was able to get my code to compile by removing all uses of this method.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the dllexport attribute on the definition and the declaration.  The definition is the source file where you have "restart" defined without the "extern" keyword.

Comment: This gives the error "error C2370: 'restart' : redefinition; different storage class".

Comment: Sorry, the definition and the declaration must match. Wording improved.

Comment: Fixes the error in the previous comment but the symbol is still not being exported. I get linking errors for "restart" when I try to use it.

Comment: How do you try to use it?  Do you declare with __declspec(dllimport)?

The advice from nobugz to just do it differently is also good.